# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting changes when new rows added

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

So I click on the cell between A and 1 to select entire sheet, then I click "Format" then "Conditional Formatting" and set the rules.  Basically, I have about 15 different conditions but all are in columns F through O so I use F:O.  For example, if text is exactly YES change the background to green.

The issue is when I add a new row, the formatting stops for that row and the F:O rules are replaced with F1:O15, F17:O59, etc. skipping row 16.

Can I use a script that will never change when rows are added?

Comment: Its new sheets. Each row skips a row so I am not sure if that affects it. For example, we have data on row 1, 3, 5, 7, etc. and then add new rows in the middle of these from time to time.  This seems to be when the issue happens so I am wondering if a script would be better, and where would it go.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up an onEdit trigger that applies the formatting every time you edit the sheet. I've provided an example of a function that would copy the format of cell A1 to all cells in the sheet. This link will bring you to Google's documentation for this type of work. 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

Here's the documentation on triggers...
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

```js
function formatRange(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1");
  
  range.copyFormatToRange(sheet,1,sheet.getLastColumn(),1,sheet.getLastRow())
  
}
```

Comment: Ok this just got over my head in a hurry :) - I assume this goes into the Script Editor found under Tools? I just need to figure out how to take the rules I have in place and "convert" them to code to use in the Script.

Comment: Yes, you would write this script in the script editor under tools. However, if you are simply copying formatting from one cell (A1 here), you shouldn't need to 'convert' any formatting to code. The code I listed would work if you just substituted "Sheet1" with your sheet's name. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok so put all of the Conditional Formatting I created in A1 instead of selecting all the cells, and then paste your script into the editor.  That makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I think that should do the trick. I haven't done much with conditional formatting, but based on Google's Documentation, this should work :)

Comment: So after a month or so, I am still running into the issue of the Conditional Formating changing the values in "Range:" when I add a new row.  For example, if my formatting is for the entire B column and then I add a row in row 35, the Conditional Formatting now has B1:B34 in the range, and row 35 has no formatting.

Comment: Are you using the onEdit trigger to run a script?

Comment: Hey Calvin, here is exactly what I have in the Scripts Editor screen:
    `function formatRange(){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("FILES");
      var range = sheet.getRange("A2:R2");
  
    range.copyFormatToRange(sheet,1,sheet.getLastColumn(),1,sheet.getLastRow())
  
    } `

Comment: Chris - I think your script should work, but you need to trigger it somehow. Click on the clock icon near the play icon in your script editor. Then select the function name under 'Run'. Then, under 'Events', you should select 'From Spreadsheet' and 'On edit'. This will cause your script to run every time the spreadsheet is edited.