# Adding new Rows changes Range cells in Google Sheets, skips new row

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

The original question was here and had an answer I thought was working: [Google Sheets Conditional Formatting changes when new rows added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049119/google-sheets-conditional-formatting-changes-when-new-rows-added)

But after a month or so of using this, I am still running into the issue of the Conditional Formating changing the values in "Range:" when I add a new row.  For example, if my formatting is for the entire B column and then I add a row in row 35, the Conditional Formatting now has B1:B34 in the range, and row 35 has no formatting.

The solution was to put this code in the Script Editor of the Google Sheet.

```
function formatRange(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var range = sheet.getRange("A1");
 range.copyFormatToRange(sheet,1,sheet.getLastColumn(),1,sheet.getLastRow())
}
```

Again, anytime a new row is added to the Sheet, the conditional formatting range info changes and skips the new row.

Comment: If you formatted an entire column, would that work for you?  Or is there formatting and/or data below the current data with different formatting?

Comment: The [tag:conditional-formatting] is for Excel. For Google Sheets use [tag:gs-conditional-formatting]

Comment: Unable to comment on Rubén's answer, I would like to point out that this wouldn't work if you choose to insert cell rather than rows. Inserting row would break up the column-tall range into two different ranges above and below the insertion point.

Answer (score 0):

If formatting and entire column is feasible, that can be accomplished in code:

```
function columnBackground() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var range = sheet.getRange("B:B");
  range.setBackground("red");
}
```

The above code formats the background of the entire column B in red.

Comment: So I put the conditional formatting in Row number 2 across all of the columns because different columns have different rules.  The actual code in the script editor is: `function formatRange(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("FILES");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:R2");
  
  range.copyFormatToRange(sheet,1,sheet.getLastColumn(),1,sheet.getLastRow())
  
}`  Because I thought this would grab any rules in A2, B2, C2, etc. to R2 and then hold their format.  But again, any time a new row is added, it changes the values.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Set the conditional formatting rule for the whole column instead of to set the conditional formatting cell by cell.

## Explanation

In the "Apply to range" setting, the range should be something like `B1:B1001`, so any time you insert a row between B1 and B1001 the conditional formatting rule will include the new row.

Note: If you use `B1:B` it will automatically be changed to set the last cell to the one corresponding to the last row in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Ok, let me give this a try.  Seems counter intuitive doesn't it? :)  It seems that B1:B would include every row ever added but let me give your solution a try.  Thanks!