# Conditional Formatting for range

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lJr2lkqaPmVjiZ9lGEk5xQh6GimsYZiOdBN9u1O5k0E/edit?usp=sharing) in which I need to apply conditional formatting to a range, but the criteria of `If text contains =D4` does not "work" properly with a range, because it returns true if the value of `=D4` is anywhere in the range, not just for each cell. The problem seems to be caused by a combination of the use of `=D4` AND the use of a range. A cell range normally works (of course), and the `=D4` normally works, but they don't work together.

**I am trying to create conditional formatting of `If text contains =D4` for a column in a sheet that a form feeds into.** The form, of course, creates new rows in the sheet, which removes conditional formatting for the new rows.

- I have tried setting the formatting with numerous scripting attempts, which I got very close, but I need to use the conditional formatting of `If text contains` not `equals` and I couldn't sort that out via script.
- I also tried copying the conditional formatting with a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049119/google-sheets-conditional-formatting-changes-when-new-rows-added), but that script creates a range in the conditional formatting, which then doesn't work with `=D4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference `=D4` is **relative**. In the context of conditional formatting, it means that the upper left corner of the range will indeed be compared with D4. The cell below it will be compared with D5, the one below it with D6, and so on.

Since the cells D5, D6, ... are empty in your sheet, everything gets colored because every string contains the empty string.

Solution: use `=D$4` instead of `=D4` in the formatting rule, making the reference **absolute**.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I can't believe I didn't realize that. Thank you!